# Какая максимальная длина пароля для password_hash(),sha512 и blowfish

Tags: php, cryptoapi

Какая максимальная длина пароля для **password_hash(PASSWORD_DEFAULT)**, **sha512** и **blowfish - crypt()**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если заглянуть в определение хэш-функции в википедии:

> A hash function is any function that can be used to map data of arbitrary size to data of **fixed size**.

Вывод хэш-функции (в php!) всегда представляет собой строку фиксированной длины, поэтому можете просто оценить длину любого из представленных алгоритмов на практике.

Если вопрос касается максимальной длины входных данных, то она может быть произвольной и ограничена сверху только оперативной памятью (в случае итерационного использования, недоступного, насколько понимаю, в PHP из коробки - длина может быть условно-бесконечной).